# How to show recyclerVIew in Dialog?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog, alert

My XML is as follows- live_test_question_change_dialog_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/live_test_change_question_option_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/a"
        android:background="@drawable/option_number_background"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ShowDialog method is as follows-

```
  /*---------------------------------------------------*/

public void showDialog(){

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext(), R.style.FullHeightDialog);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.live_test_question_change_dialog_layout);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    if (dialog.getWindow() != null){
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    RecyclerView recyclerView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.live_test_question_change_dialog_rec_view_id);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

    ArrayList<String> questionNumberList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 1; i<= testModel.getTotalQuestions(); i++){
        questionNumberList.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }

    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(questionNumberList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    dialog.show();

}

/*--------------------------------------------------*/
```

But the app crash when I try to show to dialog -

```
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

What is the problem with this code? How to solve this problem?

Comment: show xml please.

Comment: Hi. XML is given in the question.

Comment: Are you using `androidX` dependency in your project? check-in your build.gradle file

Comment: Kindly provide main xml

Comment: It is crashing in the line-   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.live_test_question_change_dialog_layout);

Comment: Yes. I am using androidX

Comment: It is working now but now the problem is     android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using `androidx` dependency

You should use

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

instead of

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

Comment: People are still using `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` in 2020.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to create a new 'fragment' which extends from DialogFragment

```
public class MyDialogWithRecyclerView extends DialogFragment
```

The official documentation is good and I've used it in order to create a Firestore RecyclerView in a DialogFragment. It's the same for a regular recycler view.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment

If you've worked with RV and fragments you should be fine but you can ask me any questions.

**EDIT**
Sorry, that version is deprecated, this is the correct documentation
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html